# Save more than one data on orientation change

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-orientation

I have to save more than one integer array on orientation change how to do it.
here is the code i seen for save one value.

```
@Override​
​​​​public ​void​ onSaveInstanceState(Bundle ​outState)​ {
​​​​​​​​//--- save​ what ever​ you​ need ​to ​persist ---
​​​​​​​​outState.putString("ID", "1234567890");
​​​​​​​​super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
​​}

@Override
​​​​public ​void​ onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle ​savedInstanceState)​ {
 ​​​​​​​​super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
 String ​ID​ = ​savedInstanceState.getString("ID");

      }
```

Comment: i have to save value of two array and two variable

Answer (score 0):

Read the Bundle documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html